# If $X,Y \in L^1$ are independent r.v then $ XY \in L^1 $

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y \in L^1$ meaning that $\mathbb{E} \{|X|\}, \mathbb{E} \{|Y|\} < \infty $. I want to show that $ XY \in L^1$ given $X,Y $ are independent random variables.

Since $X,Y$ are independent, then $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are as well independent and hence $\mathbb{E} \{ |X| |Y| \} = \mathbb{E} \{|X| \} \mathbb{E} \{ |Y| \} < \infty$ by hypohtesis and so $XY \in L^1$. Is this correct?

if $X,Y$ are not independent, do we still have that $XY \in L^1$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

If we do not assume independence, then it is not true. For example, consider the probability space $(0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure. Define $X: (0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as $X(\omega)=\omega^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Then $X \in L^1$ but $X^2=X \cdot X \notin L^1$, since $X(\omega)^2=\frac{1}{\omega}$ has infinite integral.